# How Can You Lock Rows of Cells in Excel Dynamically?

Tags: excel, vba

So I know that one can format cells to be locked and then protect a worksheet to prevent that data being overwritten. But I'm looking to be able to dynamically lock cells within a sheet. From doing some Googling I've tried adapting the below block of code for my needs. The intent is that if column A has a value the rest of the row will be locked so no one can overwrite the rest of the row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(ActiveSheet.Cells(18, 1), Target) Is Not Nothing Then
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(18, 1).Text = "X" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(18, 2), Cells(18, 20)).Locked = True
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(18, 2), Cells(18, 20)).Locked = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated, as well as tips for succinctly applying this to every row in the sheet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. As SO is not a code writing service, what we need to help you is for you to make an effort to resolve your issue first. Then post your effort in your query (in your case: code that you have). We can then help and guide (and in some instance provide updated code) you. Might be worth reading [How To ask A question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: It would be good to try posting a piece of code you created, found an tried... In principle, you must unprotecte the sheet, determine the cells which must be unlocked and proceed according to their amount against the used range. If they are only a few you firstly lock all the used range and then unlock the necessary ones. And viceversa in the other situation...

Comment: Just FYI: yes it is possible what you want to do

Comment: Is it possible to unlock the thread since I’ve added information or should I just post a new one?